# Hello world!Status: 302 Moved Temporarily Content-Type

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-302

I am very new to Google App Engine coding and have no idea how to resolve this. What I am doing is a very simple thing. I have designed and made a website on my local PC. Now to host it, I am using Google App Engine. So what do I do, I simply downloaded the python app engine launcher and uploaded my entire website on Google Apps. I have set all the redirects on the control panel of Godaddy! which has registered my domain name.

Now whenever I visit the site for the first time, I get "Hello world!Status: 302 Moved Temporarily Content-Type" message and then upon clicking refresh, it loads the website. How can I get rid of this?

Much appreciate your help on this.

Thanks